# couldn't find a null safe version of bezier_chart package flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

> Need a null safe version of bezier_chart flutter, couldn't find it, is there an alternate null safe available for this package?

Comment: `dart pub upgrade --null-safety`

Comment: Not helping, need a null safe version if available for bezier_chart alone,.. dart pub upgrade --null-safety -> shows message in terminal ' null-safety compatible versions do not exist for:
 - bezier_chart'

Comment: Dart package Support sound null safety and your package not Support sound null safety